# ZMQ route message to specific worker in a ROUTER/DEALER architecture

Tags: zeromq

When we have multiple clients that do request to multiple services how to send a message to specific worker in the ROUTER/DEALER architecture proposed by zeromq ?
More specifically, if we have `service A` `service B` behind a ZMQ_DEALER. How to send a message to `service A` or `service B` only ?

Comment: What do you meen by ROUTER/DEALER architecture?   Is it a broker with a router frontend for the clients and a dealer backend for the workers?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Majordomo pattern in ZeroMq guide

https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/#Service-Oriented-Reliable-Queuing-Majordomo-Pattern

The Majordomo Protocol (MDP) extends and improves on PPP in one interesting way: it adds a "service name" to requests that the client sends, and asks workers to register for specific services. Adding service names turns our Paranoid Pirate queue into a service-oriented broker.

[image]

Comment: Try to do not answer questions with Links. Links can be wrong in some time.

Comment: Shame this still doesnt have a c# implementation

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to send message **through** ROUTER/DEALER to specific worker. Things would became really complicated if there were (both in terms of implementation and usability).

Still, the solution is obvious: expose endpoints of worker to the clients as well as router's endpoint. If you need to send message to the specific worker - send it directly. If you need to send it to random worker - send it through router.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's meant by worker in this question but you certainly can send messages via router sockets to specific connections.

If for example a Dealer socket registers an identity then Router can speak directly to that socket using the identity - so if you have serviceA and serviceB behind two dealers then a router can talk directly to either service by prefixing an extra frame to the message with the socket identity (and using the SNDMORE flag).
e.g.

`ZMQ.Socket dealer = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER);
 dealer.setIdentity("serviceA".getBytes());`

Then a Router socket can speak directly to that dealer by sending:

`routerSocket.sendMore("serviceA".getBytes());
 routerSocket.send(data)`

There is one problem with this solution which is ZMQ remembers when sockets are no longer routable (e.g. there's been some kind of network drop or you've simply restarted the service) and will no longer route messages there if it can't, even after re-connection. So using a fixed string for the socket identity is not a great idea. I tend to use UUIDs instead. 
Telling the server which client/service has which UUID now becomes much more fun! There's a number of approaches you can take but I'll leave that for different post as it's getting away from the main point.